# Webpack: Inject javascript bundle name into server templates like JSP or Apache Velocity

Tags: webpack

I have a Java server app that uses Apache Velocity for templating. I want to use webpack to bundle up the javascript and inject the bundle name into multiple server template files at compile time. I can't use the HtmlWebpackPlugin because the template files are not valid html at compile time so it throws an error.

I basically want to inject the hashed javascript bundle name into a plain text file and copy the text file to dist. Is that possible with webpack?

**Input:**

src/index.js

src/index.vm:

src/login.vm:

```
<html>
  #if(server-logic)
    <div>hello</div>
  #end

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Expected output:**

dist/index.HTSr0MF8.js

dist/index.vm:

src/login.vm:

```
<html>
  #if(server-logic)
    <div>hello</div>
  #end

  <script src="index.HTSr0MF8.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to inject bundle names into the `vm` files, even if the html is not fully structured.

You can specify `template` option property as `js` file which will be executed in order to get the HTML.
In addition specify `inject: false` to prevent the default injection.

```js
// webpack.connfig.js

var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('../..');
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var webpackMajorVersion = require('webpack/package.json').version.split('.')[0];

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './example.js',
  output: {
    ...
  },
  module: {
    ...
  },
  devtool: 'eval',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'template.js',
      inject: false // prevents default injection
    }),
  ]
};
```

```js
// template.js

// Export a function / promise / or a string:
// This function has to return a string or promised string:
module.exports = function (templateParams) {
  // construction of your vm file
  var html =
    '<html><head>' +
    '<title>' +
    templateParams.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title +
    '</title>' +
    htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags +
    '</head><body>' +
    htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.bodyTags +
    '</body></html>';

  return html;
};
```

based on [isomorphic javascript-advanced example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/javascript-advanced)